# optimal way to use open graph for ebooks

Tags: facebook-opengraph, isbn

I am self-publishing an ebook

I read the types for open graph protocol http://ogp.me/#types

In open graph protocol, for book namespace http://ogp.me/ns/book

there are the following attributes.

book - Namespace URI: http://ogp.me/ns/book#

- book:author - profile array - Who wrote this book.
- book:isbn - string - The ISBN
- book:release_date - datetime - The date the book was released.
- book:tag - string array - Tag words associated with this book.

I can obviously fill in everything except for isbn.

I do not intend to get an ISBN for a self published ebook.

So what should I do to optimize the use of OPG for an ebook without an ISBN number?

Answer (score 1):

The book namespace seems to allow book objects without ISBN, but the newer books.book namespace http://graph.facebook.com/schema/og/books# requires it.

There is a known issue with regards to ebooks without ISBN:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238075889669083